# Sql Server nested transaction rollback @@TRANCOUNT

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions, nested

I've got a **stored procedure** which begins a **new transaction** for data manipulation. The procedure itself is executed **within another transaction**.
I have no influence what happens before my procedure. And it could change.

My idea is to check the `@@TRANCOUNT` before I begin the nested transaction. Then check the `@@TRANCOUNT` again in catch block and compare it. In no case I want the outer transaction to be rollbacked. So i wonder if i am safe with this code?

thx for your help!

```
SET @TRANSCOUNTBEFORE = @@TRANCOUNT; 
BEGIN TRANSACTION tx;
BEGIN TRY
  /* some data manipulation here */
  COMMIT TRANSACTION tx;       
END TRY            
BEGIN CATCH
  IF @@TRANCOUNT > @TRANSCOUNTBEFORE ROLLBACK TRANSACTION tx;
  /* some error handling here */   
END CATCH;
```

Comment: have a look at the documentation: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189336(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: There are no "nested" or autonomous transactions in SQL Server; your rollback affects all active transactions in the current scope, regardless of how many levels deep you are. The only way you could do this (and I haven't even tested it, nor do I recommend it) is to go outside the SQL Server process (e.g. SQLCLR) and start a different transaction in a new process.

Comment: oh, i see _rollback...transaction_name can refer only to the transaction name of the outermost transaction_ thank you. So I have to execute the procedure at another event being sure that there are no other open transactions.